How to go from $\operatorname{Spec}$ to $\operatorname{Proj}$? (Eisenbud-Harris Proposition III-36)
I have a question about Proposition III-36 from Eisenbud-Harris' Geometry of Schemes, which I have included below (I have also made marks where I think there might be typos, but I may be wrong).

In the first part, they define an $A$-algebra homomorphism\begin{align*}A[x_{0},\ldots,x_{n},\tfrac{1}{x_{i}}]&\longrightarrow T\\\tfrac{x_{j}}{x_{i}}&\longmapsto\tfrac{\alpha_{j}}{\alpha_{i}}\end{align*}
From what I understand, there is an induced map $\operatorname{Spec}T\to\operatorname{Spec}(A[x_{0},\ldots,x_{n},\tfrac{1}{x_{i}}])$ on the specs in the other direction, but they write that this gives us a map $\operatorname{Spec}T\to U_{i}=(\mathbb{P}_{A}^{n})_{x_{i}}$, which would be $\operatorname{Proj}(A[x_{0},\ldots,x_{n},\frac{1}{x_{i}}])$, wouldn't it? So to get a morphism $\operatorname{Spec}T\to\mathbb{P}_{A}^{n}$, I'm imagining it's something like this:$$\operatorname{Spec}T\to\operatorname{Spec}(A[x_{0},\ldots,x_{n},\tfrac{1}{x_{i}}])\stackrel{??}{\to}\operatorname{Proj}(A[x_{0},\ldots,x_{n},\tfrac{1}{x_{i}}])\hookrightarrow\operatorname{Proj}(A[x_{0},\ldots,x_{n}])$$
So my question is how do we get from $\operatorname{Spec}(A[x_{0},\ldots,x_{n},\tfrac{1}{x_{i}}])$ to $\operatorname{Proj}(A[x_{0},\ldots,x_{n},\frac{1}{x_{i}}])$?
Many thanks in advance!

$U_i$ is an affine open subset of $\mathrm{Proj}(A[x_1,\dots,x_n])$. It is the subset which classically corresponds to ${ [a_1,\dots,a_n] \in \mathbb{P}_A^n , | , a_i \neq 0 }$.

One typographical tip: $\operatorname{Spec} T$ for $\operatorname{Spec} T$ produces more attractive spacing than  $\mathrm{Spec} T$ for $\mathrm{Spec} T$.

Thank you for your response. May I ask how the $\operatorname{Spec}$ fits into the $\operatorname{Proj}$? I understand that $U_{i}=\operatorname{Proj}(A[x_{0},\ldots,x_{n}]){x{i}}$ is a subset of $\operatorname{Proj}$, but I don't see how the $\operatorname{Spec}$ fits into it.

It seems like your have some misunderstandings about nonvanishing sets inside Proj. $(\Bbb P^n_A)_{x_i}$ is the open set of $\Bbb P^n_A$ where $x_i$ does not vanish, which is the spectrum of the homogeneous localization (i.e. the degree-zero elements of the typical localization) of $A[x_0,\cdots,x_n]$ at $x_i$, and this ring is $A[\frac{x_0}{x_i},\cdots,\frac{x_n}{x_i}]$.
In particular, the $A$-algebra homomorphism defined in the first part is not from $A[x_0,\cdots,x_n,\frac{1}{x_i}]$, it is from $A[\frac{x_0}{x_i},\cdots,\frac{x_n}{x_i}]$. The chain of morphisms at the bottom of your question therefore goes $$\operatorname{Spec} T \to \operatorname{Spec} A[\frac{x_0}{x_i},\cdots,\frac{x_n}{x_i}] \cong (\Bbb P^n_A)_{x_i} \to \Bbb P^n_A$$ where the first map is the $A$-algebra homomorphism defined above and the second map is the canonical open immersion.
 PS: I agree with all of your red typo highlights. 

Thank you, this helps. I'm sorry, I didn't realise there was a difference between $A[\frac{x_{0}}{x_{i}},\ldots,\frac{x_{n}}{x_{i}}]$ and $A[x_{0},\ldots,x_{n},\frac{1}{x_{i}}]$, but the latter is bigger than the former. Then we identify $\operatorname{Spec}A[\frac{x_{0}}{x_{i}},\ldots,\frac{x_{n}}{x_{i}}]$ with $U_{i}$ by preimage under localisation map, is that right?

@anonanon444 For any graded ring $R$ with homogeneous element of positive degree $r$, we have that $D_+(r)\subset \operatorname{Proj} R$ is $\operatorname{Spec} R_{(r)}$ - this is a fundamental property of the proj construction. Depending on your source, this could either be a definition, or an early result. In your case, flipping to the definition of projective space in Eisenbud and Harris early in the text, they construct $\Bbb P^n_A$ by gluing $\operatorname{Spec} A[\frac{x_0}{x_i},\cdots,\frac{x_n}{x_i}]$, so in this case you just have one of the affine opens that was glued together.

Okay, I've found where it is, thank you again.

Sorry to revive this: I had a question about the converse as well, but I wasn't sure if I should make another post. In the converse, they associate the morphism with the point $(\frac{x_{0}}{x_{i}},\ldots,\frac{x_{n}}{x_{i}})$. But the point is supposed to be from $T^{n+1}$. So do they mean the image of each $\frac{x_{j}}{x_{i}}$? In that case, I'm not sure how you would do the scaling they mention in the last line. Would you scale, then take the image, and then have to verify that those two points are equivalent?

@anonanon444 They're playing a little fast and loose with the notation by identifying things with their images - one way to make this more precise is to let $\alpha_k$ be the image of $\frac{x_k}{x_i}$ in $T$ under the map of $A$-algebras $A[\frac{x_0}{x_i},\cdots,\frac{x_n}{x_i}\to T$. Then the scaling in the last line proceeds by letting $\alpha$ be $\beta_i$, the image of $\frac{x_i}{x_j}$ in $A$ under the map of $A$-algebras $A[\frac{x_0}{x_j},\cdots,\frac{x_n}{x_j}\to T$ (this comes from the assumption that $p\in U_j$).

I think I understand now that we can use that the map is an algebra homomorphism to apply the scaling. Thank you for the clarification!
